# Permission issues setting up hidden service

Tags: onion-services, debian

I am trying to experiment with running my blog as a hidden service. I am using debian on a vps to host my blog. I am using apache2 run as user www-data.

I had to chown /var/www/wordpress to debian-tor to get the private key and hostname created. This broke my clearnet facing blog so I chowned it back to www-data. How do I deal with the fact that both tor and my webserver want to own the webroot? I tried adding debian-tor to www-data group and vice versa but no luck. Sorry if my english is bad.

torrc

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/www/wordpress
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

Apache listen port 80

tor log:

```
warn /var/www/wordpress is not owned by this user (debian-tor but by www-data) perhaps you are running tor as wrong user
warn error loading rendezvous service keys
err set_options() Bug: Acting on config options left us in a broken state
```

Answer (score 2):

The Tor Hidden Service dir should **not** be set to the same directory as your web root (it contains your private key among other things, which you don't want to serve up on your website)

Use a separate directory that is only accessible by your Tor user. Eg.

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/myblog/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

and then be sure to set some appropriate permissions:

```
chown -R debian-tor:debian-tor /var/lib/tor/myblog/
```

Comment: Thank you. I feel very stupid now for some reason I was thinking the HS dir had to be webroot.

Comment: No worries; it happens. If this solved your problem don't forget to mark it as the answer so others will know that it worked. Thanks for using Tor.SE!